# Copy values of one field to another during indexing

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

To index data we have to create  document  which has a field contains value of other fields. We getting data from multiple tables.

**Table A**
id
name
create_date
update_date
bId

**Table B**
bId
bname
title
source
release_date

**Table C**
cId
bId
fname
lname
...

According to requirement the title filed should have value of other filed

Ex:- "title":[title,create_date,update_date,source]

please suggest us that it is possible in elastic search or not. If possible how we will achieve it as we are using river plugin to index the data

```
PUT /_river/person/_meta
{
"type": "jdbc",
"jdbc": {
     "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "sql":" query to get data"
    "index": "test_search",
    "type": "person"
},
"bulk_size" : 10000,
"flush_interval" : "2m"
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can copy fields into the `title` field using the `copy_to` feature in your Elasticsearch mapping:

> Adding copy_to parameter to any field mapping will cause all values of this field to be copied to fields specified in the parameter. In the following example all values from fields title and abstract will be copied to the field meta_data.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#copy-to

First create an index with a mappping in Elasticsearch. This mapping is copying `updatedDate`, `createdDate` and `source` into the `title` field when a `person` document is indexed.

```
POST /demo
{
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "createdDate": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "copy_to": "title"
                },
                "updatedDate": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "copy_to": "title"
                },
                "source": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "copy_to": "title"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now index a document (your river will index documents, but to test this approach you can index a document manually):

```
POST /demo/person/1
{
    "title": "test title",
    "updatedDate": "2011-09-30",
    "createdDate": "2011-09-30",
    "source": "person source"
}
```

If you search on the `title` field for a value in the `source` field, there will be a match.

```
POST /demo/person/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "person"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on elastic search, so where to add copy_to parameter in river based query.  please help me